# Can I assume a role from only an iam group in another account?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

I have an EKS Cluster in account B, account B has a role which; when assumed.. gives access to that cluster.

However, I want to assume that role from another account... Fairly straight forward, but the kicker is I want only users which are members of a specific IAM Group in account A to be able to assume said role in account B?

Is that possible? If so what would the policies look like?

EDIT:

Been having a think, and maybe this is possible and perhaps easier than I first though;

This is my policy in account B...

```
Version = "2012-10-17"
Statement = [
  {
    Action = "sts:AssumeRole"
    Effect = "Allow"
    Sid    = ""
    Principal = {
      AWS = "arn:aws:iam::AccountB:root"
    }
  },
]
```

Then I have a group policy in Account A:

```
{
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Action": [
                "sts:AssumeRole"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:iam::AccountA:role/test-role",
            "Sid": "AllowAssumeOrganizationAccountRole"
        }
    ],
    "Version": "2012-10-17"
}
```

Is this just a case of putting arn of the group from account A in place of the root account in the policy of account B, and then putting the arn of the role in account b into the policy in account A?

Surely it's not that simple? I need to test.. but keen to hear from those who have a deeper knowledge of IAM if this is the correct approach.

Comment: IAM groups can't be a principle in IAM roles or resource policies.

Comment: Ah crumbs! Is this possible at all then?

Comment: Probably, its possible, through some `Conditions` in the policies.

Comment: I'm not sure where that condition would need to be. Perhaps we look at this with a different approach... if we add a policy to Account B allowing users to assume a role, and then add the role to the policy of the group in Account A - Would that have the same effect?